# Sort two datatables columns with date and images

Tags: datatables

I use `datatables` and sort two columns by german date with the plugin `datetime-de.js`. In one column I insert a picture in the cell if a date for that record is not given.
When I use the date format for one column, the sort works. But for both the sort breaks (cick on sort the second column)
How can both columns get sorted by ignoring the rows with the pictures?

```js
                        $(document).ready(function() {

                          $('#liste').DataTable({  

                                    dom: 'Bfrtip',                            

                                    fixedHeader: {
                                                    header: true,
                                                    footer: true
                                                },
                                    
                                    order: [[ 0, 'asc' ]],

                                    paging: false,

                                    columnDefs: [{ type: 'de_date', targets: 1,
                                                type: 'de_date', targets: 0},
                                                ],

                                    language: { 'decimal': ',',
                                                'thousands': '.',
                                                'sEmptyTable': 'Keine Daten in der Tabelle vorhanden',
                                                'sInfo': '_START_ bis _END_ von _TOTAL_ Einträgen',
                                                'sInfoEmpty': '0 bis 0 von 0 Einträgen',
                                                'sInfoFiltered': '(gefiltert von _MAX_ Einträgen)',
                                                'sInfoPostFix': '',
                                                'sInfoThousands': '.',
                                                'sLengthMenu': '_MENU_ Einträge anzeigen',
                                                'sLoadingRecords': 'Wird geladen...',
                                                'sProcessing': 'Bitte warten...',
                                                'sSearch': 'Suchen',
                                                'sZeroRecords': 'Keine Einträge vorhanden.',
                                                'oPaginate': {
                                                'sFirst': 'Erste',
                                                'sPrevious': 'Zurück',
                                                'sNext': 'Nächste',
                                                'sLast': 'Letzte'
                                                },
                                                'oAria': {
                                                'sSortAscending': ': aktivieren, um Spalte aufsteigend zu sortieren',
                                                'sSortDescending': ': aktivieren, um Spalte absteigend zu sortieren'
                                                }
                                                
                                             }, 
                              
                                            
    });
                        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.11.5/sorting/date-de.js"></script>

<table id="liste" class="display" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">
<thead><tr><th align="center">Column1</th><th>ColumnDatePicture</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>14.01.2022</td><td align="center">29.03.2022</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>14.01.2022</td><td align="center"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Face-smile.svg" title="smile"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>15.01.2022</td><td align="center">27.03.2022</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>16.01.2022</td><td align="center"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Face-smile.svg" title="smile"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>14.01.2022</td><td align="center">27.04.2022</td>
</tr>

<td>14.07.2022</td><td align="center">27.05.2022</td>
</tr>
<td>14.06.2022</td><td align="center">27.04.2022</td>
</tr>
<td>14.05.2022</td><td align="center">26.04.2022</td>
</tr>
<td>14.04.2022</td><td align="center">24.05.2022</td>
</tr>
<td>14.03.2022</td><td align="center">17.04.2022</td>
</tr>
<td>14.02.2022</td><td align="center">13.04.2022</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>14.01.2022</td><td align="center"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Face-smile.svg" title="smile"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>

<tfoot><tr><th align="center">Column1</th><th>ColumnDatePicture</th></tr></tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `data-sort` or `data-order` property on the table cell. [Link to documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html)

```html
<tr>
    <td>14.02.2022</td>
    <td align="center" data-order="13.04.2022">13.04.2022</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>14.01.2022</td>
    <td align="center" data-order=""><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Face-smile.svg" title="smile"></td>
</tr>
```